# Base64 Decode Spits out Wierd Symbols

Tags: python, hash, encoding, base64, decode

So I have an encoded string:

```
aGFzaF92YWx1ZT1rBeEt0RJ1BNdkxlfbEZBZGoRrcU5UbHhBPT0
```

If, I decode it, I get,

```
hash_value=k�-�u�d�W��Y�kqNTlxA==
```

Please note some of those characters may have been lost when I copied it. I used this website to decode: https://encoder.mattiasgeniar.be/index.php

I am going to attempt to run this through a python script but these symbols are messing up my output, any ideas on whats causing them? and or how to fix it? Do I need to encode the base64 string or decode it in utf-8 or something? I'm clueless here, thanks in advance!

Comment: Your decoded output is correct, the string is just mangled. Try https://www.base64decode.org/

Comment: You have a base64 string with *binary data*; not all data in that string is meant to be interpreted as text, that's all. What data did you expect instead?

Comment: Try [http://www.asciitohex.com/](http://www.asciitohex.com/) as well.

Answer (score 1):

The data you are showing maybe be in a format that can not be easily printed to the screen. For example it could be encoded binary data or something.

Base64  can encode the characters in a format that can be easily transferred and read in different areas. Typically when handling data like this you will decode it and do some processing with the data, and not necessarily show it.

Answer (score 0):

Your encoded string doesn't look like a base64 string. Usually they end with an `=` sign.

Using that website you linked, I was able to encode and decode with python2.
Here are my steps

1. Encode string
   [image]
2. Copy Base64 value[image]
3. Run python and decode:

code

```
>>> import base64
>>> base64.b64decode('dGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3Q=')
'this is a test'
```

Comment: = is the padding character for many Base64 variants; there can be one, two, or zero equals.  Note that it can also be suppressed in other variants (i.e. if there are = signs, remove them.)